Which movie has a kid entering a cartoon?
When I was little, I saw on Cartoon Network a movie with a kid that talked on the phone with a friend of his. Then he turned into a cartoon, got a red car and started a row of adventures. The first adventure was falling asleep in the car and missing a turn on the beautiful road, so that he entered a swamp. At one surtain point, he learned about infinity. When the story from the cartoon ended, he woke up (the image was on film now) and his friend was still on the phone, telling him that he was only gone for a minute. Do you have any idea how the movie is called? Thanks!

How many years ago did you see it, approximately? And was this cartoon recent or old back then?

OK, this is The Phantom Tollbooth from 1970. A kid talks on the phone then turns into a cartoon and goes on adventures in a red car (and gets stuck in a swamp). In the end, it's live action again, and his friend tells him on the phone that he was only gone for 5 minutes. It was based on the book by Norton Juster. Here's the trailer:




This was my first thought on reading the question too.  Also the point about learning about 'infinity' - the story has him visiting a mathematical city and then a literary city, and learning things about them.

Great book, I didn't see the movie. I remember one of the stories was about seeing from "a different point of view", and him levitating and looking around wildly before crashing back down.

JohnP, sorry for writing here, I couldn't think of any other way. By this comment I assume it was you who upvoted some of my answers yesterday. I'm afraid the votes were reversed as 'serial voting', but thanks anyway. It's the thought that counts. :)

Does this movie have a scene in the animated world where there's a conductor who is using his baton to control the weather or time of day or something, but the boy disturbs him and the sky goes haywire?
